# could not get column property error that i can not figure out

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Can please someone tell me what the problem is with this code. If i uncomment the code on error resume next the code works. but without i get error, could not get column property, invalid argument. This happens when i click in de listbox. I can not figure out what the problem is. i have a sheet whit 14 columns, starting from A, offset 1 row

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()   
  Dim say, lastrow As Long, a As Byte
  'On Error Resume Next
'ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0
OptionButton1.Value = True
For a = 0 To 15
Controls("textbox" & a + 1) = ListBox1.Column(a)
Next a

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate

say = ActiveCell.Row
TextBox15.Value = say
Sheet1.Range("A" & say & ":N" & say).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your listbox actually have 15 columns  if not 'ListBox1.Column(a)' will cause errors when a goes above the number of columns?  Generally I expect at most a couple columns in a single listbox.  Also 'rows.count' will probably cause an error as it needs the worksheet name 'Sheet1.rows.count'

Comment: thank you for replying. Yes my sheet has 14 columns. 0 - 15 Controls("textbox" & a + 1) = ListBox1.Column(a) is where i get the error.

Comment: in your macro your reference `ListBox1.Column(a)` which means your listbox needs 15 columns (not your sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Likely your listbox has less then 15 columns.

`ListBox1.Column(a)` will cause errors when a goes above the number of columns you have in the listbox (not the sheet). Generally I expect at most a couple columns in a single listbox.

Also `rows.count` will probably cause an error as it needs the worksheet name `Sheet1.rows.count`

Comment: if i hover over with the mouse in debug, it shows a = 14

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim price As Double
price = 0

Sheet1.Activate
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "40;50;40;65;65;180;40;40;60;40;60;30;30;60"         'Column Widths Of Listbox
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 14                                                        'Column Count Of Listbox
ListBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A2:N" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value